# Using a for-loop and range function vs a while-loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, while-loop, range

I'm looking for a function like range except that the step is a fraction of the previous number generated. So if the fraction was 99/100 the set of numbers might be something like this: 100, 99, 98.01... 0.001

Would this be more efficiently done with a for-loop and range-like function or with just a while-loop?

The code I have so far:

```
stop = .001
current = 100
while current > stop:
    #code
    current *= 0.99
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your function, really. No additional packages needed.

Comment: @Jan. It's slow, and doesn't store the results. While not strictly necessary, numpy is better suited for numerical manipulation than vanilla python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html):

```
np.geomspace(100, 12.5, 4)
```

You can use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with direct exponentiation:

```
12.5 * 2**np.arange(3, -1, -1)
```

[`np.logspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) is also an option:

```
100 * np.logspace(0, -3, 4, base=2)
```

Comment: How would I use these if the fraction was .99?

Comment: @Brandon. Pretty straightforward. Last example you can just change the base.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does that:

```
def fract(current, stop, fraction):
    l=[current]
    while l[-1]>stop:
        l.append(l[-1]*fraction)
    return l

>>> fract(100, 0.001, 0.5)
[100, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125, 1.5625, 0.78125, 0.390625, 0.1953125, 0.09765625, 0.048828125, 0.0244140625, 0.01220703125, 0.006103515625, 0.0030517578125, 0.00152587890625, 0.000762939453125]
```

If you don't want the last item (it's smaller than stop) just add `l.pop()` before the return